# Run a cron with 2 commands, and wait for first to finish to run second

Tags: callback, cron, command, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I don't have enough memory ram in my digitalocean droplet ( I know, I should optimize the running modules and the code instead, and I'll Do that, but I need to buy some time until I Can Do it.. )

I'd like to create a cron every few hours that runs this:

```
sudo sync
sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```

But I would like to make sure that the first is finished before run the second,

How could I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `&&` if you only want to execute the second command if the first command succeeds.

```
sudo sync && sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```

Use `;` if you would like to execute the second command regardless of the result of the first command.

```
sudo sync; sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```

This `cron` will run the commands every hour:

```
0 * * * * sudo sync && sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```

However your should setup the `root`'s `crontab` instead of running the commands with `sudo`. `sudo` is not necessary to run your commands in this context, since it'll be invoked as `root` anyway. This opens up `root`'s `crontab`.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

The `cron` without `sudo` will look like this.

```
0 * * * * sync && sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```